# I won't tip the dealer, will I be thrown out?

Tags: etiquette

I am going to play in an American casino for the first time tomorrow. I won't tip the dealer, ever.

Is that ok? Will I be thrown out?

Answer (score 1):

No you won't be thrown out.

Some small things though, and this depends obviously on the limits you're playing, but what you can expect:

- Dealers getting a little annoyed with you. I was a dealer for years, not American, but have worked in the WSOP and I can tell you the hourly rate dealers make in America is nearly all gone to tax, without tips they make nothing. So expect some flak for it. Personally I never expected a tip, mainly because in Europe we were paid a good wage for basically throwing cards at people.
- If you're playing higher limits and you have a good dealer, expect the players to give you a lot of flak. I'm talking 25$/50$ limits and plus. The player playing these limits appreciate good dealers, which I can tell you especially when the WSOP is on is a rare thing, because they train 1,500+ dealers 6 weeks before the WSOP and throw them into the deep end. Odd thing, but I've had a table basically flip out a player for not tipping.
- If you're playing low limits, I'm talking 1$/2$ to 2$/5$ you might get some players calling you out on it, mainly because people are drinking, having a good time and to them it's a casual fun game.

So to sum up, no you will never ever be thrown out. American dealers will expect a tip if it's a cash game, because unless they're on a duel rate spot, they're not making money otherwise. Spoiler if you're playing in the Rio during the WSOP no one is on a duel rate spot, pretty much every other casino will have their cash dealers on duel rate anyway. Especially places like the Venetian, Bellagio or Caesars. So you can expect some flak for not tipping, but hey that's your business, so just wear headphones and you'll hear nothing then :)

Comment: Tip the dealer, tip the waiter/tress. As I saw it (once, in the USA) (and made me laugh a lot)  `Tipping is **not** a city in China`

Comment: What is dual rate

Comment: A dual rate dealer is someone who can take over for a floor when needed, as such they are paid a better rate than a basic dealer. Just a fancy name for someone whois a dealer with more responsibilities who are paid better.

Comment: Dual rate is someone who receives dealer rate when dealing and is also qualified for the floor, and will receive floor rate when working on the floor. If they are dealing to you they are making the dealer rate of the duality of rates.

Answer (score 0):

I've not played in America either, but if they throw you out for that then they don't deserve your business. I'll refer you to another answer I wrote which has a similar sentiment. What you choose to do with your own money is entirely your choice. Anyone who says otherwise should be ignored.  (https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/295/88)